# How to change vue-toasted pop-up direction

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-toasted

I'm using vue-toasted to show notifaction.

By default, it pops down to top.

Code:

```js
<v-btn @click="onTest" />
...

onTest() {
  this.$toast.info('Test!', {
    containerClass: 'toasted-container',
    className: 'toasted',
    keepOnHover: true,
  })
},
```

nuxt.config.js:

```js
toast: {
  duration: 3800,
  action: {
    icon: 'mdi-close-circle',
    onClick: (e, toastObject) => {
      toastObject.goAway(0)
    },
  },
  iconPack: 'mdi',
  icon: 'mdi-check-circle',
},
```

The toast pops down to top.
I tried to add some css like `transition`.
I'm not familiar with CSS, so I guess it's wrong.

How can I change it to right to left?
I couldn't find any info on their [GitHub](https://github.com/shakee93/vue-toasted).

Comment: The `position` option doesn't work for your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some `@keyframes` and `animation`, it worked.

```
@keyframes in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 100%
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0%
  }
}

.some-class{
  animation: in 300ms;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`vue-toasted` v1.1.27 only supports animating [upward](https://github.com/shakee93/vue-toasted/blob/73814a2/src/js/animations.js#L9) or [downward](https://github.com/shakee93/vue-toasted/blob/73814a2/src/js/animations.js#L9). It has no API to add new animations.